# Segmentation Fault after google-library 1.0.1 update

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

After every successful step on https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/

I now am hard stuck.

I can not get the line: "googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id "project id" --device-model-id "model id" " to work.

nor can i get the line "google-assistant-demo --project-id "project id" --device-model-id "model id" " to work.

I keep getting the error code: "Segmentation fault" (nothing else)

Note that i do get every other test to work, like the audio test and the "googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk" flawlessly.

I have been looking for answers but most of the answers are outdated and have been solved by updating to the latest google-library (1.0.1).
Since i already have that installed (also checked pip list to be sure) must mean that i realy am stuck.

Is anyone able to help.
That would mean the world to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved, for all people who get this 'segmentation fault', the solution is simple, download the previous version of rasbian ( Raspbian Stretch )

Google assistant is not compatible with Raspbian Buster.

Leave a like if this solved your problem